# CPU usage boosting to 190% when using UIAlertView on main thread and Unable to cancel the alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a method called errorHandle which gives the alert view and I am calling this method in the @try block

```
-(void) errorHandle {

    UIAlertView *disp = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid QR Code" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [disp show];
    //[disp dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}


@try{

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     [self errorHandle];
 });

}
```

Here I am getting the alert view but when I tap on the cancel button,the alert view is dismissing and appearing back again . I could not dismiss the alert view with single tap but after tapping several times the alert view is dismissed but the CPU usage during the operation boosted to 190%.

After the alert view is dismissed ,I again tried to get the alert view again I have to tap the cancel button several times. Is there anyway to dismiss the alert view properly on main thread and make it not to appear again?

I tried the following code but it didn't work out for me

1)

```
UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

2)

```
__block UIAlertView *alert1 =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [alert1 show];
    });
```

Can we generate alert view in `@finally` block

is this possible?

```
@finally{

// alert view code

}
```

Can anyone answer me about these two issues?

Comment: The problem is that `[self errorHandle]` is being called repeatedly, but since you didn't show the context in which that line appears, no one can tell you why.

Comment: I am building a sample QR code scanner and I am scanning the QR code and If the code is valid it displays a msg saying that code is valid, else errorHandle method is called. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: I asked for nothing. I've explained the problem as best I can from the little information you've given. The alert view reappears because you are calling `errorHandle` again and again. But I can't see the code that calls it. You can. Figure it out and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint matt. I used break points to figure out which part of code is calling the errorHandle method repeatedly and I corrected it.